# Proving Lagrange's Theorem with Galois Theory

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

**Problem:** Let $G$ be a finite group with subgroup $H$.  Let $|G| = n$ and $|H| = m$.  Prove that the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$ using **only** results from Field and Galois Theory, with the exception of [Cayley's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem).

**Attempt:**

1. Let $f$ homomorphically inject $G$ into $Sym(G)$ via Cayley's Theorem.
2. Let $g$ then isomorphically map $Sym(G)$ onto $S_n$.  Then $(g \circ f): G \rightarrow S_n$.
3. From (2) we have that $G$ and $H$ can both be taken to be isomorphic to subgroups of the group $S_n$.
4. So now let $S_G$ and $S_H$ be the isomorphic copies of $G$ and $H$ respectively inside $S_n$.
5. Let $E$ be an arbitrary field extension of $F$ s.t. $[E:F] = n$.
6. **Assume we can identity the permutation elements of $S_G$ and $S_H$ with $F$- automorphisms of $E$.  Assume further we can do this in such
   a way that $S_G$ has as fixed field $F$ and $S_H$ has as fixed field
   $B$ s.t. $F \subset B \subset E$ under field inclusion.**
7. Then the Tower Lemma states that:

   $$
   [E:F] = [E:B] \cdot [B:F]
   $$
8. By Galois Theory we have that $[E:F] = |S_G|$ and $[E:B] = |S_H|$ since $F$ and $B$ are the fixed fields of $S_G$ and $S_H$ respectively.
9. Then we have

   $$
   |S_G| = |S_H| \cdot [B:F]
   $$

   so that the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$ as desired.

**Questions:**

(1) Is this argument the right way of going about the problem, or it wrong?

(2) Assuming this is the right way of going about the problem, how could the assumption in (6) be justified?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have *first* to embed the extension $\;E/F\;$ in a **Galois** Extension $\;K/F\;$ s.t. $\;F\le E\le  K\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Why is that?

Comment: Otherwise point (8) may not work, @Loose Shus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory